# « Implantation » et « implementation »

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Je lis deux ouvrages : un français et un anglais. Le français est la traduction de l'anglais.

Dans l'anglais on lit :

> Implementation of models in structural analysis codes.

Dans la version française on lit :

> Implantation des modèles dans des codes de calcul de structures.

Je me demande pourquoi on dit « implantation » et pas « implémentation » (dans la version française) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le traducteur a probablement mal compris les [recommandations de l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/implementer).

> [Implémenter] signifie, en parlant d’un logiciel, l’« installer en réalisant les adaptations nécessaires à son fonctionnement ». On le traduit dans ce cas par implanter (implanter un logiciel). Il signifie d’autre part « effectuer l’ensemble des opérations qui permettent de définir un projet et de le réaliser ». On le traduit alors par implémenter (implémenter un système d’exploitation).

Ici, le terme adéquat est bien sûr *implémenter* puisqu'il s'agit d'une mise en œuvre, pas d'une installation.

Comment: Merci. Alors Implanter c'est un synonyme de installer (de même pour la couple implantation-installation), non ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais utilisé l'expression « implanter un logiciel » (ça semble vouloir dire placer un logiciel à un endroit où ce n'était pas prévu) et utilise très rarement « implémenter un logiciel ». En informatique, ce qu'on implémente est plutôt un algorithme; c'est à dire qu'on met œuvre l'algorithme, que l'on passe de la théorie (équations, formules) à la pratique (code source). L'implémentation, c'est la réalisation.

Comment: @jlliagre > je n'ai jamais utilisé "implanter" un logiciel non plus, par contre j'ai déjà très souvent entendu que des consultants aidaient à implémenter tel ou tel logiciel (exemple:SAP) chez les clients. Il semble que cela soit erroné si l'on en croit l'Académie française.

Comment: @LaurentS. Les académiciens ne sont pas spécialement des informaticiens... mais « aider à implémenter un logiciel donné », ça a du sens et c'est justement le deuxième proposé par l'Académie : opérations qui permettent de définir et réaliser un projet (ici le déploiement de SAP chez un client).